# Why is there /index.php/ in all my links? How do I remove it?

Tags: url-rewriting, 404-error, links, slug, directory

I recently realized that my rss feed is not working, because a plugin was assuming it's under

> mydomain.com/feed

But it isn't. I get an 404 error. I figured out that instead my feed is under

> mydomain.com/**index.php**/feed

I already had similar issues in the past when using Easy Affiliate Links.
For example when I created a link that was supposed to be:

> mydomain.com/visit/google

The link that worked was

> mydomain.com/**index.php**/visit/google

My blog url is equally annoying:

> mydomain.com/**index.php**/blog

It's not a minor annoyance any more. I need to get "index.php" completely removed from my url structure. I'm assuming it's some kind of misconfiguration. How do I fix it?

Comment: What kind of server are you using? Do you have an .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm on hostgator. But I just solved the problem by browsing all the menus. Will post my answer soon. For some reason Settings->Permalinks was set to Custom configuration.

Answer (score 2):

After browsing all my dashboard, the solution turned out to be simple:

Navigate to:

Dashboard -> settings -> permalinks

For some reason "Custom structure" was activated. I simply had to choose "Post name" instead.

Now all my links look as they should.

Comment: The reason could be that WordPress was no able to detect that mod_rewrite module was active on the webserver. Then all urls had to be relative to index.php.