# Error updating pages, and linking to pages (permalink error)

Tags: permalinks

There is a chance this has been answered elsewhere - I have searched as thoroughly as I can here and elsewhere.

I have the following errors on my site, wonkylogic.co, (hosted on LAMP server on Digital Ocean, I followed their tutorials):

1. Could not create directory for theme installation. I manually created the directory over ssh to fix this; but may still be relevant to my other errors.
2. When updating a page: “Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.”  I’ve found various “solutions” to this: editing .htaccess multiple ways, editing Apache config, editing urls in mysql database. Tried them all and they didn’t fix anything. **Change permalinks** to plain or /index.php/<post_name>.  Changing permalinks works - I can update pages. But obviously this isn’t a real solution because now I have SEO unfriendly urls and all external links to my site are broken.
3. Navigation to webpages generates a 404 error. This is fixed by changing the permalinks as in 2. above. Again not an ideal fix.

So the overarching questions are “Why is my site broken this way?”  and “How do I fix the root problem?”

Additional context: I migrated my site from shared hosting to Digital Ocean using WP-migrate plugin. It appeared to work for a while, got totally broken after installing SSL with Let’s encrypt. I’ve basically rebuilt the LAMP stack and after much blood sweat and tears got my site vaguely visible as it is now (http only right now - one step at a time).

As an interim measure I will set up some custom redirects to the new urls for external visitors using a plug-in I’ve found.

***Update: it seems that my website may not even be accessible, I'm not sure why but I can access it via Safari, but not with Chrome or Firefox.***

Seeing what's in .htaccess was requested.

```
==================== .htaccess ====================                                                
#Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPres>
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress f>
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwr>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
================== END .htaccess ==================
```

Comment: What is in your .htaccess file?

Comment: 1. sounds like file system permissions and ownership are improperly configured. 2. is probably any PHP error being generated while handling an AJAX request, and thus polluting the JSON response - you should be able to see the error by checking the HTTP response body using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Hi @QStudio , I've added the .htaccess file contents to my OP.  TBH now I'm looking at the contents afresh I don't know how some of that got in there originally (obv Wordpress added the contents in it's section) but the rewrite rules above that I don't recall putting there.

Comment: @bosco, please could you help me out by being a little more specific of what you mean by checking the "http response body …"?

Comment: If you have `WP_DEBUG` & `WP_DEBUG_LOG` enabled, these errors should also be recorded in the log. But the dev tools Network tab records HTTP requests which the web page is making. If you have the tab open and recording when you attempt to publish a post, you'll see a new request made, probably to something like `index.php?rest_route=` - if you select that request, and then the "Response" tab of the inspector panel for that request, you will be able to directly inspect the server's response. And there you will likely find that some extraneous output has messed up the JSON

Comment: I will set up WP_DEBUG and see if I can catch the error when I reproduce it.  I couldn’t track anything down via the Inspector panel but when I installed the Redirection plugin it flagged exactly the kind of error you were mentioning.

Comment: Hi again @bosco, You are definitely onto something. I set up the WP_DEBUG routine but WP cannot log to it it seems:
1. I had to manually create the debug.log file over ssh as it was not present when I repdroduced the error.
2. After creating the file and reproducing the error the log file remained empty.
So it seems WP cannot write the file or into it.
In your view who should own the WP directory & files within, the tutorial I followed said www-data, but does this paragraph (wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#regarding-automatic-updates) mean my user or DB owner?

Comment: WP_DEBUG log yielded 3 errors in this file - canonical.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php
But I don't know what that means or how to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well a notice-level error won't crash anything on it's own, and without WP_DEBUG enabled that probably shouldn't be responsible for messing up the JSON response. It sounds like you may need to inspect that JSON response in the Network tab to see for sure what's going on - it sounds like perhaps it might not be a PHP error after all.

Comment: I've had a go inspecting the Network tab on Firefox (preivously used Safari and couldn't see anything of value).  I could see a lot of responses which I tried to look through but there's a heck of a lot to look through.  The only thing I noticed appear in hte inspector when the JSON error is thrown is a 404 error (under a XHRPOST header or something).  Error message:
`https://wonkylogic.co/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/64?_locale=user
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 85ms]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the root cause of why I was getting the invalid JSON response and why permalinks had to be set to include index.php in all urls.
My Apache configuration file was not allowing overrides and I think that means Wordpress was unable to alter files in my directory.
The setting for my directory was:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This was changed to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Errors no longer plaguing my site.  Thank you to everyone who took the time to respond.

Comment: How I figured this out was by reading a comment left on the answer to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244076/why-is-there-index-php-in-all-my-links-how-do-i-remove-it
I then searched how to fix the mod_rewrite error, and followed instructions here: https://www.tinytumbleweed.com/posts/wordpress-permalink-problem-mod_rewrite/